# Reading INI file is not working using IniRead in AHK

Tags: autohotkey

I am trying to read a INI file and get the values from it using AHK. However, the read is not successful and I am getting the `default` value from the call every time.

Here is the code I used :-

```
ReadIniFile(IniFileName, SectionName, KeyName,ByRef Value)
{
   If FileExist(IniFileName)
   { 
     MsgBox File found ; this comes
   }

   IniRead, Value, IniFileName, SectionName, KeyName , Default
   MsgBox %Value% %IniFileName% %KeyName% %SectionName% ; Value comes as 'Default'
 }
```

The output is :-

```
Default C:\Users\barmans\Desktop\ECU.h ININame GeneralSettings
```

The function call is :

```
ReadIniFile(HeaderFileName, "GeneralSettings", "ININame",    AutoTestScript)
```

The INI is in format :-

```
[GeneralSettings]
ECU=ABS8_B
ININame=ABS8_B_Test.ini
KBDiagPath=C:\KBApps\Knorr-Bremse\KB Diag
RunCount=0
[LogSettings]
LogFileName=ABS8_B_Report.log
TraceLevel=1
```

Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As you did in `MsgBox`, you have to enclose your variables with `%` percent signs.

If the documentation tells you to state a "name", "value" or anything like that, you'll need an actual string or integer. Other than that, sometimes you're asked to state a "variable name", in which case you obviously must not use `%` - as in function calls.

So, your iniread will look like:

```
IniRead, Value, %IniFileName%, %SectionName%, %KeyName%, Default
```

for more detailed information, visit http://ahkscript.org/docs/Variables.htm. Tho I do not see anything about the use of variables in command there

Comment: I am confused here. Why will `%IniFileName%` will be treated as variable, while `Value` is not a variable ?

Comment: that's because you gotta pay close attention to the documentation. @ iniread, about `OutputVar` (here: `value`) it says: "THE NAME OF THE VARIABLE in which to store the retrieved value". On the other hand, `filename` is supposed to be "The name of the .ini file". Mark the difference, as described in my answer above.